# Open different websites from within an app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I would like to have an app which simple opens different websites for different languages. So the main purpose of the app is simple to redirect to an web app. My questions:

- does Apple allow such apps (in the Appstore of course) ?
- how can it be achived to be listed in the different istores (by country, according to the language)
- how to I open different websites for different languages?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Apple does allow Apps that just contain UIWebView pointing to a website.
- Use `NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];`
  to find the Country code
- Using a simple condition, set the URL relavent to the country code.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, it is allowed, though discouraged and highly annoying. I immediately uninstall apps that do this.

2) You'll have to setup localization for your app for each language you would like to represent

3) You simply setup a web site, and write it in the language you would like on the site.  Localization will save time here, too.

Although this might draw some traffic to your sites, it is not a good business model and you should probably try to make your app do something of benefit for the user.  If your app is useful, you will get more than enough traffic to your sites through gentle prodding or in-app announcements of some kind.